# Ao modificar um dado antes de enviar para a Query ele atualiza a tabela

Tags: java, query, hibernate, spring

Estou fazendo uma query select com o spring + hibernate,

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlBase);
```

Eu estou passando para o 'sqlBase' uma Empresa como parametro,

```
SELECT e.* FROM Empresa e WHERE e.id = :empresa
```

Nessa empresa eu modifico alguns dados antes de passar para essa consulta, troco um dado do objeto EMPRESA, quando eu envio para a Query ele acaba ATUALIZANDO esse dado que eu modifiquei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

O que provavelmente está acontecendo é o seguinte:

Você tem o objeto Empresa e ele está na sessão do Hibernate. Assim que você modificar esse objeto e realizar um flush(), os dados serão atualizados.
Então, o que está ocorrendo e que ao realizar uma nativeQuery, o Hibernate provavelmente está realizando esse flush.

Possíveis soluções:

1) Você pode obter a instância da Empresa de forma apenas leitura.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

2) Você pode modificar essa nativeQuery para ser uma query HQL, e isso talvez resolva se não for chamado nenhum flush ou save da sessão do Hibernate.

Recomendo fortemente a utilizar a primeira caso não tenha interesse em alterar a entidade.

Para maiores informações: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html

Comment: Poxa que coisa especifica, mas show de bola resolvi utilizando a anotação nas rotinas que tenho de query, só um detalhe até aonde pude constatar tanto quem query native quanto nas "normais" que utilizam hql ele acaba fazendo o flush. Obrigado pela ajuda!